# Why did Jango user a saberdart?

Tags: star-wars, attack-of-the-clones

The [Kamino Sabredart](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Kamino_saberdart) is an **instantly recognisable** piece of kit that leads a Jedi investigator directly to its user.

Why would a professional like Jango use such a distinctive weapon when he could have used a cheap blaster or a slug-thrower that would have had zero chance of onward detection?

[image]

Comment: On a related note, why did Jango go through the trouble of hiring another assassin to use a droid to use poisonous worms if he was going to go to Coruscant anyway?

Comment: @RogueJedi - He'd used her before. She was an infiltration and assassination specialist. Jango is more of a one-man-army kinda guy

Comment: He couldn't just program the droid to go to Padme's apartment himself?

Comment: @RogueJedi - He sub-contracted the job to her. She's the pro, he isn't; http://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/154155/20774

Comment: Kamino was known by only a few people and wasn't even in the Jedi Archives, so it was unlikely that anyone would recognize it. It was instantly recognizable only to Dexter, but Obi-Wan caught a lucky break there (which means the Force had a hand in it).

Comment: @Null - I'm not so sure. The Visual Dictionary even calls him on it for using such a distinctive piece of kit.

Answer (score 12):

Kaminoan Saberdarts, in fact, were **not** easily recognizable. In [a deleted scene](https://youtu.be/LDPmS7a1UYo?t=119) (from where the screenshot is originally) in *Attack of the Clones*, an analysis droid at the Jedi Archives informs Obi-Wan Kenobi:

> **SP-4:** As you can see on your screen, subject weapon does not exist in
>   any known culture. Probably self-made by a warrior, not associated
>   with any known society.

Also, if we can go along with the Legends, [Wookieepedia says](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Kamino_saberdart/Legends):

> In [Star Wars: Bounty Hunter](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Star_Wars:_Bounty_Hunter) Jango Fett uses these darts even though he
>   hasn't become involved with the Kaminoans at the time, these darts may
>   be similar darts which Jango later replaced with the saberdart.

So, Fett had been using Saberdarts for a some time, and he knew they could not be recognized; except by a former gunrunner and mine prospector, who just happened to know them from his personal past:

> **Dexter Jettster:** Well, whattaya know... I ain't seen one of these
>   since I was prospecting on Subterrel beyond the Outer Rim!

Comment: The analysis droid was probably thrown by the fact that Kamino (and presumably *all references to things Kaminoan*) had been removed from the Jedi archive by Dooku.

Answer (score -1):

Jango Fett works for Dooku and Dooku works for Palpatine. Palpatine doesn't really want Padme dead (she is very useful for him, being Anakin's weakness). In fact he does everything to get them together after failed assassination attempt. What Palpatine really needs is that Jedi discover Kamino and Clone Army, in order to proceed with Sith Grand Plan culminating with Order 66.

Kamino was erased from Jedi Archives (in Legends it was Dooku before he left the Order) , to allow cloners some secrecy while creating the Clone Army. But now, this army is completed, and Jedi would have to be led to Kamino, without raising suspicion. And what better way then to create emergency where Jedi like Obi-Wan Kenobi, with lots of connections in underworld, would "unexpectedly" find trail that leads to Kamino. IMHO, **Zam Wesell was set up to fail** and that is the real reason Fett didn't try to kill Padme by himself - he would succeed, but then Clone Army would not be discovered. In worse, Military Creation Act would pass and Republic would have regular (non-clone) army which would be much harder to control .

Out-of-universe, Lucas is simply not very good in storytelling. He needed some reason to bring main characters (Anakin and Padme) back together and in spot light, but he also needed some reason to explain discovery of Kamino. Therefore, he invented this rather convoluted and illogical  story with outsourced assassination contract and strange dart.

Comment: This simply isn't accurate. There's every indication that Jango and Zam were trying really quite hard to kill Padmé and that Dooku had no idea that the Jedi had traced Jango to either Kamino or Geonosis. I guess you could argue that it's all part of a grand plan by Palpatine (courtesy of his precognition) but that stretches reality to breaking point. That just isn't how Force visions work.