# What did Palpatine want to happen in the days after his first attempt to assassinate Amidala?

Tags: star-wars

I have no clue what his plan was here other than start the Clone wars.

He wanted emergency powers and if he got that by blaming the Sepratists for the assassination how would he get the Clone army from Kamino without looking suspicious like he knew about the army already?

I doubt he told Dooku to hire the Clone template, have him hire someone else, and when they fail have him use a specific dart that is only traceable by a few people. This would align with him picking Obi-Wan and Anakin though, as it would allow him to get in Anakin's mind and drive him to Tatooine, and him possibly knowing Obiwan has contacts that will allow him to get the darts origin figured out. But that is so farfetched so I doubt that was the plan.

So my question really is, what was Palpatine's plan in Attack of the Clones overall?

Comment: I don't think he cares that much what happens, so long as it causes chaos.  He controls both sides in the war, and pushing the situation toward crisis can essentially always be manipulated to allow him him cement greater and greater degrees of authoritarian control.

Answer (score 4):

It was required to get Nute, the leader of the Trade Federation to sign on.

> Count Dooku : We must persuade the Commerce Guild and the Corporate Alliance to sign the treaty.

> Nute Gunray : What about the Senator from Naboo? Is she dead yet? I'm not signing your treaty until I have her Head on my Desk!

It was also helpful in pushing Anakin to go to the dark side.

The ideal would have that she died, hence why they hired a first rate assassin, Jango Fett, with a flawless record.

Unfortunately, for whatever reason such as a wish for privacy Jango used a second rate assassin Zam Wesel with a weaker record. She fucks up the assassination, and upon being captured within a few seconds tries to reveal the identity of Jango Fett, necessitating he assassinate her, with [a nigh undetectable weapon.](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/156610/why-did-jango-user-a-saberdart)

This weapon is detected by the dedicated sleuthing of Obi Wan, who discovers the clone factory after this. This leads to the unfortunate situation where the Jedi have a clone army on Geonosis and they are not wiped out, necessitating order 66 in the third film to kill them all.

Palpatine rolled with the punches, but we have no real evidence that this was what he wanted to happen. His motives are fairly clear- he wants a strong Sepratist movement so he can have an extended war between the Republic and it, kill all the Jedi and gain supreme emergency powers during it, and corrupt Anakin to his side. The events of this film somewhat disrupt these plans.

Comment: There's also the fact that Padmé is a far more capable and headstrong senator than he wants. Having her out of the picture means that her replacement will be much more biddable.

Comment: You arent answering my questions. Look at your last lines: 
"His motives are fairly clear- he wants a strong Sepratist movement so he can have an extended war between the Republic and it, kill all the Jedi and gain supreme emergency powers during it, and corrupt Anakin to his side. The events of this film somewhat disrupt these plans." I want to know what his original plan was before the events disrupt it. My question has less to do with Padme and more to do with Palpatine's plan.

Comment: I said- he wanted Nute to sign up with him, and Anakin to turn to the dark side. Ideally, Padme would die. In terms of finding the army, having it found later after the Jedi died would be better. He can handle getting a proxy to find them easily enough.